# Why should I reference equals x to x==y and y to x==y?

Tags: c#

Please see the code below, which I took from here: https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/

```
    public int CompareTo(Natural x) { return CompareTo(this, x); }
    public static bool operator <(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) < 0; }
    public static bool operator >(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) > 0; }
    public static bool operator <=(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) <= 0; }
    public static bool operator >=(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) >= 0; }
    public static bool operator ==(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) == 0; }
    public static bool operator !=(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) != 0; } 
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return CompareTo(this, obj as Natural) == 0; }
    public bool Equals(Natural x) { return CompareTo(this, x) == 0; }

// negative means x < y 
// positive means x > y 
// zero means x == y 
// two nulls are equal 
// otherwise, null is always smaller 
private static int CompareTo(Natural x, Natural y) { 
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) 
        return 0; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) 
        return -1; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) 
        return 1; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(x, Zero)) 
        return -1; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(y, Zero)) 
        return 1; 
    else if (x.head == y.head) 
        return CompareTo(x.tail, y.tail); 
    else if (x.head == ZeroBit) 
        return CompareTo(x.tail, y.tail) > 0 ? 1 : -1; 
    else 
        return CompareTo(x.tail, y.tail) < 0 ? -1 : 1; 
}
```

What does the variable zero mean? I assume is it declared and initialised like this (based on what the comments say):

```
var Zero = zero means x == y;
```

Why would you reference equals x to x==y and y to x==y?

Comment: `var Zero = zero means x == y;` makes no sense as code. `means` isn't a keyword in c#. The comment `zero means x == y ` is describing the behaviour of the method. If it returns zero it means that `x==y`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you jumped into the middle of that series but part 2 discusses the Zero and One static variables: https://ericlippert.com/2013/09/19/math-from-scratch-part-two/

Answer (score 3):

`Zero` is presumably a static instance, for example:

```
public static readonly Natural Zero = new Natural(0);
```

As for why you would compare the values to `null` and each-other: you compare to `null` so that you can avoid a `NullReferenceException` in the checks that involve `x.tail` or `y.tail`, and allow sorting a list with `null` references in it to work correctly, with all the `null`s going to either the start or the end (but: consistently). You compare `x` to `y` because a: any object when compared to itself should report "match" (return `0`), and b: when both `x` and `y` are both `null`, we should *also* return "match" `0`. Doing a reference-check on `x` and `y` solves both of these common scenarios conveniently.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2013/09/19/math-from-scratch-part-two/ talks about the creation of that static value if you wanted to reference it and its actual creation code (which is not far from what you have).

Comment: Why are static variables used rather than instances.  Does it matter?